# How to make postman trust certificates using chain "ISRG Root X1"?

Tags: ssl, postman, lets-encrypt

I was using Postman to test all my APIs on a server with SSL certificates generated using letsencrypt. As the root certificate (DST Root CA X3) expired yesterday, I am not able to use any APIs from the postman. But the same APIs are working fine with SSL from the web browsers and using curl. Let me know How can I make the postman trust the new root certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update postman to 9.0.5 released on Oct 2, 2021

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/10338

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Postman on Linux? If so, this gist may work,, perhaps.

https://gist.github.com/kujiy/67ef342170c4b0a36bb4bd9615ae2916